# How to convert procedure from SQL Server into Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I am newbie to Oracle. I want to convert a procedure from SQL Server.

This is my procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETMONITORING]
    @namabarang varchar (max)=null,
    @PeriodeAwal varchar (max)=null,
    @PeriodeAkhir varchar (max)=null,
    @JenisLayanan varchar (max)=null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
        @nWhere varchar(4000),
        @Select varchar(4000),
        @from varchar(4000),
        @Where varchar(4000),
        @final varchar (4000)

    SET @Select = 'select * '
    SET @from = 'from table  '
    SET @where = 'where 1=1'

    IF isnull(len(@namabarang), 0) <> 0
       SET @where = ISNULL(@where, '') + ' and namabarang like ''' + ISNULL(@namabarang, '') + ''' '

    IF isnull(len(@JenisLayanan), 0) <> 0
       SET @where = ISNULL(@where, '') + 'and jenislayananid like ''' + ISNULL(@JenisLayanan, '') + ''' '

    IF isnull(len(@PeriodeAwal), 0) <> 0 and isnull(len(@PeriodeAkhir), 0) <> 0
       SET @where = ISNULL(@where, '') + ' and tanggalpermohonan between ' + @PeriodeAwal + ' and ' + @PeriodeAkhir

    SET @final = @Select + @from + @where

    execute (@final)
END
```

I have tried to convert to Oracle. This is my stored procedure in Oracle

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GETMONITORING
(
    v_namabarang in varchar2 default null,
    v_JenisLayanan in varchar2 default null
)
AS
  v_where  VARCHAR2(200);
  v_Select VARCHAR2(200);
  v_from   VARCHAR2(200);
  v_final  VARCHAR2(200);
  v_result VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  v_Select := 'select * ';
  v_from   := 'from permohonan ';
  v_where  := 'where sysdate=sysdate ';

  if namabarang is not null
     then v_where := v_where || ' and namabarang like '%' || v_namabarang || '%'';

  if jenislayanan is not null
     then v_where := v_where || 'and jenislayanan='||v_jenislayanan ;

  v_final := v_select || v_from || v_where;

  EXECUTE immediate v_final INTO v_result;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
END;
```

When I compile that stored procedure, I get an error:

> Error(37,50): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "%" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || member submultiset

Could you help me to fix this ?

Is my stored procedure in Oracle correct in logic?

How do I call that stored procedure in sqlplus ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to escape the single quotes in '%' i.e. use ''%'' instead.

Comment: An `IF` block must be "closed" with an `end if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the extra single quotes around the constants:

```
if namabarang is not null then
    v_where :=v_where || ' and namabarang like ''%' || v_namabarang || '%';
end if;
if jenislayanan is not null then
    v_where :=v_where || ' and jenislayanan = '''|| v_jenislayanan || '''';
end if;
```

Comment: @AufalAhdy - there was an extra single-quote at the end of the second line which has now been corrected. Try it again.

Comment: @BobJarvis i've tried again. copy paste. And the result "Error(53,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     if "

Comment: Ah - it looks like you need two `END IF;` lines, one before `if jenislayanan...` and another at the end of the above fragment. In PL/SQL an `END IF;` is required for each `IF`, as PL/SQL is based on Ada, not on C. Best of luck.